# How to create a side by side bar chart with 3 columns that have the same values but no identifying column

Tags: tableau-api, stacked-bar-chart

I am trying to make a side-by-side bar chart that has the sum of values 0-10 for each column. In the original data set, there is no 0-10 column. It's just Age1 (0-9), Age2 (0-9) and Age3 (0-10) and 40 other variables of numbers/characters if that makes sense. I want to make a chart that shows the total number for each value in Age1, Age2, and Age3. How do I make the x-axis groups to just be 0-10 then the y axis a sum of each age group? Sorry if this explanation is confusing. I have attached an image that accomplishes the sum of Age3 but only because it's group by Age3.

[image]

I tried grouping it by Age3 and it gives me age codes 1-10. I tried sum of age1 & age2. I tried grouping Age1 but it'll give me the same output but with the correct sums for Age1. I also attempted a calculate field with all three age groups but that just messed it up.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using?